# Can't resize UIView in IB

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

Probably something simple, but I can't figure why I cannot resize a UIView in a xib in Interface Builder.

I created a new view XIB in xcode and in the size inspector, the width and height are disabled and grayed out to 320 by 460. This is strange since I can change the size for the other two views (associated with the other two tab bar items).

I am not sure if this has anything to do with but I recently updated the sdk to 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 83):

In order to achieve that in XCode 4.6.3/5.0.2 you need to follow the screenshot below:

1. Under 'File Inspector' -> untick `Use Auto Layout`
2. Click on Attributes Selector & Choose `Freeform` for Size

This is needed when creating a headerView for a tableView

[image]

Answer (score 81):

I think that you cannot edit the size while simulating any user interface elements such as the status bar in Interface Builder. You could try turning the simulated elements off if any are enabled. Not exactly sure why this is, so would appreciate feedback from anyone who knows why exactly this is - there must be a good reason.

Comment: Thanks that's right. After I upgraded xcode and IB the status bar was on by default. The others have it at off.

Comment: As at Xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0.1 this has changed. My answer below explains how this can be achieved.

Comment: Very helpful. Just turn off the status bar, adjust the size and then turn status bar back on again.

Comment: This setting worked for a ViewController.xib in Xcode 4.3.3: "Simulated metrics - Size: freeform". After that, the view size setting is enabled. Also remove the "View mode" scale to fill option (just below simulated metrics).

Comment: uuuugh I really dislike this IDE

Answer (score 39):

The part that you are looking for is on the first Inspector panel (Command-1).  Right at the top there is a section that is labeled Simulated User Interface Elements.  By default the Status Bar is on.  You need to make sure all three are set to None.

Comment: Thanks, these answers just saved me a ton of time! Anyone know why IB does this?

Comment: Thanks mate. I've been looking for that one.

Comment: Note to all, this is now: "Unspecified" instead of none. (I have version 3.2.3)

Comment: I confirm for iPad is "Unspecified", thank you Thomas Mon, you saved me some hours :D

Comment: I only see this for View Controllers, not views

Answer (score 26):

As at Xcode 4.2, iOS 5.0.1, the default simulated metrics include simulating the 'size' attribute of UIViewControllers to 'Inferred'

If you change this attribute to 'Freeform' then you are able to resize the UIView contained within the UIViewController while also simulating the status bar (or any other of the simulations for that matter)

Comment: The size attribute now defaults to "Retina 4 Full screen", but changing it to "Freeform" still works.

Answer (score 4):

Just go to the inspector, go to the first panel (or press command-1) and then change the fields marked Status Bar, Top Bar, and Bottom Bar to None under the section called "Simulated User Interface Elements".  You may need to click the little triangle to make them visible.

Answer (score 1):

Funny I have a similar problem. I've removed all views from the xib file and re-added a view. Set the status bar to being "unspecified" so that the status bar is not accommodated for. The view, when added, get created with x=0, y=0, w=320 h=460 instead of (0,0,320,480) as I would have expected. After changing the height to 480 and connecting it to file's owner and changing the color to make it distinctive in relation to the background. I fount that there was a white band between the top of the screen and the view. 
I augmented my code with:

```
#define RECTLOG(rect)    (NSLog(@""  #rect @" x:%f y:%f w:%f h:%f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height ));
```

within viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RECTLOG(self.view.frame);
}
```

Turns out that the view is as it's loaded from IB is actually (0, 20, 320, 480)
As a work around I reset the view's frame with self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

I'm using IB 3.2.5

I'd love to know of a little fix for this one.

Comment: FYI, you can use NSStringFromCGRect(rect) to get a printable string representing a CGRect.

Comment: That was a great FYI, I checked it out, and you can actually get a string value from a CGPoint and CGSize too! very cook, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that the UIView automatically created when creating the xib file cannot be resized from the sizing panel or the edge handles.

All I did was to add another UIView and dragged everything from my old UIView to the new one then deleted the old one.

It solved the problem for me but yes, I think there is an underlying issue with the interface builder for Apple to solve (somebody correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm Using XCode 4 integrated Interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out in a different way...

open your xib with your favourite text editor and edit this line

```
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="CompassViewController">
```

`CompassViewController` is your class name you are trying to link your nib/xib with.

Just edit your class name with the correct class name and you are done ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image]In storyboard select the UIVIew and go to the attributes inspector change the UIVIew size to "FreeForm" instead of "Inferred"

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 13

Storyboard -> Attribute inspector -> Size -> Freeform

[image]