# How to show status bar on top of custom camera overlay?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, show, statusbar

I have this critical issue with showing top statusbar on the custom camera overlay which seems impossible for me at the moment. I posted the same question to Apple dev forum but did not get any response for some time now. 
In my application, I have a custom overlay view set as the overlay to the UIImagePickerController. At the bottom of the custom overlay view (this is a UIViewController), I have put a toolbar that enables user to click on toolbar items. Since the top statusbar is not shown when the camera opens up, the whole screen get pushed upwards and makes a narrow white color gap between the bottom of the screen and the bottom tool bar.

I am not aware of how to resolve this issue, but I think if we can show the top status bar on the top of the camera then this will be automatically get resolved. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip domino, I found how it should be done from this thread and resize the main uiview to 320x480 instead of default 320x460. Hope this will help someone else. Thanks.

[Can't resize UIView in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087676/cant-resize-uiview-in-ib)

Comment: Glad I could help. Its always good to accept an answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem a while back and all I did was resize my view. Why not try that and see if it works.

If that doesn't work then showing the status bar should be

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks domino, I tried the later solution but did not work for me. However, how did you resize your view ? What I did was, created a new UIViewController and created all the customized stuff there and set its view attribute as the camera overlay as below,


self.camOverlay = [[CameraOverLayController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CameraOverLayController" bundle:nil cameraView:self];
 self.camOverlay.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
 [picker setCameraOverlayView:camOverlay.view];